# How to print filenames when using MPV's EDL mode

Tags: playback

I have an EDL file, which contains a bunch of different media files, along with timestamps in each file of when to start playback and playback duration, formatted for use by `mpv`.

As I understand it, `mpv` creates a virtual file of sorts from all these little segments and then plays that file. What I would like to know is if there is some way to get `mpv` to print each filename as it switches to a different file. I would like to see the filename from each segment as it plays.

At the moment when I run `mpv playlist.edl`, it prints the name of the first file in `playlist.edl`, but that filename stays as the segments in subsequent files are played.

Where should I be looking? A custom plugin? Should this be posted on an entirely different SE site? I'm a bit lost here.